# While loop bugs

Tags: java

Hello I am a beginner Java programmer. My Program keeps ending when I put the correct number in (with out printing the message ), or it wont go from a lower number to a higher one with out ending?
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
package week3;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Week3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);   

    int Guess ;
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    int c = 55;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Higher / Lower game! Try to guess the" 
    + "number between 1 and 100. ");


    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    Guess = In.nextInt();


    if(Guess == c)
    {

        System.out.println("The number was 55 you guessed correctly! "                    
        + " it took you " + count +" tries");            
     }//end if

   while (Guess < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the guess needs to be a number between 1 and"
        + " 100. Please try again:");
        Guess = In.nextInt();

    }//End while < 1

   while (Guess > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the guess needs to be a number between 1 and"
        + " 100. Please try again:");
        Guess = In.nextInt();

    }//end while <100

    while (Guess >= 56)
    {
        System.out.println("The number is lower.");
        Guess = In.nextInt();
    }   //end while over 55  

   while (Guess <= 54)
    {
        System.out.println("The number is higher.");
        Guess = In.nextInt();
    }//end while lower than 55


 }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your issue is?

Comment: Please spell out the exact logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Why so many loops ? You should have only one loop and several `if/else if` (or a `switch`).

Comment: Consider reading about how `while` loops work. You need one `while` and multiple `if` blocks in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the problem, but you would be better off trying to find it yourself.  (Or having another go ...)

Hints:

1. Try hand-executing the code.  Pretend you are the computer, and use a pencil and paper to simulate what it would do.
2. Have you tried using a debugger?
3. Some of the comments are good hints too.

---

While I have your ear, you *also* should pay attention to your programming style.  And one *universal* style rule for Java is that variables should start with a lower-case letter.  Your `In` and `Guess` variables violate this.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Welcome to the Higher / Lower game! Try to guess the" 
+ "number between 1 and 100. ");

while (true) {
System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
Guess = Integer.parseint(In.nextLine());

if(Guess == c)
{

    System.out.println("The number was 55 you guessed correctly! "                    
    + " it took you " + count +" tries");
    break;    
 }


if (Guess < 1)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, the guess needs to be a number between 1 and"
    + " 100. Please try again:");

}


  if (Guess > 100)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, the guess needs to be a number between 1 and"
    + " 100. Please try again:");


}

if (Guess >= 56)
{
    System.out.println("The number is lower.");

} 


if (Guess <= 54)
{
    System.out.println("The number is higher.");

}
}





}

}
```

Hopefully this gives you the idea of using the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your program is incorrect.

You only need *one* while loop. Begin your program with a while loop, and continue with conditions, such that:

```
    boolean numFound = false; 
    while (!numFound) { 

        //conditions
    }
```

Comment: I am such a nerd. I get it now. One loop with the if statements inside. Thank you all so much for the help, and the advise. I really appreciate it!